# Custom Application Form (Houzez)

Tags: c#, wordpress-rest-api

Asking help folks,

We are trying to create a custom application using houzez theme and we want to get details(auto capture) on listing properties once the click the button to apply "Fill Application Form" they will redirect to the custom app https://orcarealty.org/ApplicationForm?ManagerId=%2201%22&ManagerName=%22Jurry%22&ManagerEmailAddress=%22pajares.jurry22@gmail.com%22&PropertyId=%2202983%22&PropertyAddress=vancouver

Like for example if the client wants to rent this property: https://wordpress-1154453-4376425.cloudwaysapps.com/property/5-6-w-17th-avenue-vancouver-west/

I want to get the detail dynamically:

Comment: I recommend taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. The [edit] accordingly.